# Silence Deprecation warnings Rspec Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, suppress-warnings

Is it deliberate? I mean the output message says something along the lines of

```
If you need more of the backtrace for any of these deprecations you can 
configure `config.raise_errors_for_deprecations!`, and it will turn the
deprecation warnings into errors, giving you the full backtrace.
```

I guess nobody has ever contemplated a potentially more realistic prospect, based on the thousands of views these questions have been getting?

```
If you would prefer not to receive these friendly warnings configure 
`Config.no_more_warnings_please_thanks_all_the_same`
```

I've tried

```
To disable warnings when running rake test add $VERBOSE=nil into your spec/spec_helper.rb
```

And

```
ActiveSupport::Deprecation.behavior = :silence
```

and

```
ActiveSupport::Deprecation::DEFAULT_BEHAVIORS[:silence] = Proc.new {|message, callstack| }
```

I even put it before the

```
Bundler.require(*Rails.groups)
```

Numerous expressions of concern appear that some may not understand the gravity of the situation. i.e.

```
 "It's not good to ignore warnings. You should be reading all of them......"
```

Any ideas? Surely someone has worked it out. Someone from the Rspec community possibly?

I would like to suppress all warnings actually. Not that I would be ignoring them of course. But if I'm just making some simple reluctant edit to a paying clients legacy product I don't think it is fair on them to have to spend time and money on dealing with warnings.

I'm not very experienced at programming as is evident from my reputation points so please sympathise with my frustration.

Answer (score 3):

--Use with caution--

First off, generic warning about removing warnings.

Secondly, this is what I did. In the RSpec.configure block, add the following lines of code.

```
 config.before(:all, silent: true) do
    @with_warnings = $VERBOSE
    $VERBOSE = nil
  end

  config.after(:all, silent: true) do
    $VERBOSE = @with_warnings
  end
```

I put this in the rails_helper. On the describe blocks that I don't want returning warnings, I tag them with silent: true.

```
describe "Is foo bar?", silent: true do
  # testing all the things
end
```

That will suppress EVERYTHING, including warnings about constants and undefined variables. The results of the test will still be intact and will let you know that foo, in fact, does not equal bar.

--Use with caution--